# Joomla - Component 404 and blank front Page

Tags: joomla, components

I am currently running Joomla 1.5, I have moved my site to a new domain and thought I had foloowed the procedure correctly. But now my menus are gone and it seems like articles are not showing up in their proper modules. Other than that the components i was using are now giving me a 404 component not found error. Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix this? Please I really need some help or direction....

Thanks

Here is my link: http://davidjamesmedia.ca

Comment: Can't fix what we can't see, your link shows no errors to try and resolve.   What components are in play here that are showing 404.  Joomla itself is "finding everything", so it would seem that some component(s) are in question.

Comment: The componenets that are broken are: JCE, RokCandy, sh404SEF. Where would I look in the ftp to ensure these got migrated correctly?

Comment: There are thousands of files in question here - I'd just re-upload everything.  FYI, your question says blank front page and 404 errors, when I visit your link, I see the home page (just no menus or other links)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the menus are setup in the backend, the module positions are set and ready, its just that menus and content are not showing up in their module positions...

Comment: Sounds then, like it might be the Rockettheme Template - I've never spent the time to figure out how RT and Gantry keep their settings, but that might be a starting point.

Comment: Try setting the default template to one that came with Joomla and see if they appear then.  If they do, you need to check the RT/Gantry settings.

Comment: Yes it is a rockettheme theme! I have tried to switch templates but my content still doesn't show up

Comment: How do I check the RT/Ganrty Settings?

Comment: From the Admin/Template Manager for your chosen RT Template. Those are all the settings for your chosen RT (RocketTheme) template.  As I said, I don't know much about where/how they're stored, so if a standard Joomla template shows the missing content, and your RT template doesn't, then those template settings are likely the problem.  In the past, I've re-installed RT templates to get "Joomla" right, then overwrite the freshly installed template folder with the one that has it configured the way I want.

Comment: Everything seems to be configured correctly... daaaamn I'm stumped.. for some reason I think t has to do with my components not being found 404

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the following things:

1. Ensure you made the correct database setting changes in the configuration.php
2. Ensure you server is running PHP 5.2+
3. Make sure your MySQL version is arounf 5.0+ but also not too high such as 5.5.24 this can cause some problems with depreciated functions.
4. Also make sure your server has Apache mod_rewrite extension installed if you were using SEF before else you can turn SEF off in the configuration.php

Comment: My database settings are correct. My php version is 5.3.10, not sure of my MySQL but will check it soon.  not sure if Apache mod_rewrite is installed but "Use Apache mod_rewrite" is set to yes and $sef = '0';